# Python multivariable assignment

Tags: python

```
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 3
>>> c = 7
>>> a, b, c = 3, a, b
>>> b
5
```

I am playing around with variable assignments and noticed that when I do multivariable assignments, b is assigned the value of a although I have just assigned a new value of 3 to a. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

You're first packing the three values into a tuple and then unpack that tuple into `a`, `b`, and `c`, respectively, so at the moment that `b` gets assigned its new value, the value of  `a` does not matter anymore.